# Why are list elements in Python indexed from left to right? How can I reverse this?

Tags: python

I am used to coding in VHDL  and I am new to Python. I was wondering why array elements are numbered from left to right instead of right to left as it is computer architecture. For example

```
>>> x = [3, 4, 5]
>>> print(x[0])
3
```

Here I expect `x[0]` to be 5. It has been a great source of confusion for me. Is there any way to make all arrays starting from right to left?

I edited the question according to one of the comments. In VHDL there are two options for declaring signals.

```
signal test_signal : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0001";
```

Here 3th bit is MSB and 0th bit is LSB.
so test_signal(0) would be '1'

```
signal test_signal : std_logic_vector(0 to 3):="0001";
```

now 0th bit is MSB and 3th bit is LSB.
so test_signal(0) would be '0'

I was wondering if there is a way to do that in python?

Comment: Note that also in VHDL arrays are indexed from left to right.

Comment: Dont expect all programming languages/softwares to be same. If you want it to be 5, you can use the x[-1] and work your way from there using the len() to know when to stop.

Comment: As far as I can tell, indexing in Matlab works from left to right, too.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Vectors in VHDL are indexed from right to left an example is  --> signal test_signal_vector: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0001"; -->
signal sample_bit: std_logic; --> sample_bit<=test_signal_vector(0)    -->  sample_bit would be '1'

Comment: @FranciscoParrilla Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it and works great! I can keep using the same index and just need a minus sign.

Comment: @elec_hi That's still from left to right, only the indices are a descending integer range in this example. No matter if you write `a to b` or `a downto b`, the index for the leftmost array element will be `a`, and the index for the rightmost array element will be `b`.

Comment: This probably comes from the days of C, where an array is pretty much a pointer to the memory location of first array element: `char* a` is the same as `char[] a`. Accessing the 2nd element means to go to memory location of first element plus the size of an element (`*(a + 1)` is the same as `a[1]`).

Comment: @Robert Thank you. That might be the case Because in hardware description languages such as  VHDL and verilog and in while accessing memory, the least significant bit is the right-most one.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I see your point. I tried to declare an array in python  in a descending integer range  (similar to downto) but it gives me an error. I assume it  is not possible to do that in python

Answer (score 2):

I don't know VHDL and Matlab, but I think that in nearly all programming languages you have arrays/lists indexed from the start to the end.

If you want to flip the list, you can call `x.reverse()`

This method doesn't return anything, it just modifies the existing list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually tried reversing but I keep making the same mistake with reversed array.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=[3,4,5]
x.sort(reverse = True)
print(x)
print(x[0])
```

Use `reverse = True` in `sort()`. Here the sort() function sorts the list in ascending order but if you pass reverse argument in it, then it will sort the list in descending order.